# Using a tilt sensor with NPN transistor

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, voltage-regulator, sensor, buzzer

i'm making a fall prevent circuit and i want to make sure that this circuit is correct which i made

I would like to check because I don't have enough budget and time to buy many other parts

[image: tilt sensor circuit]

and this is my tilt sensor datasheet
[image: tilt sensor datasheet]

this is my questions

1. i put the C2, C3 Electrolytic capacitors (as the datasheet says)

   can i replace C2, C3 to ceramic capacitors? (smd type 0608 size)
2. do I need to add electrolytic capacitors or ceramic capacitors to the buzzer for the life of the buzzer

Comment: How does it prevent "falls" --> *i'm making a fall prevent circuit* <-- do you mean an excess tilt angle warning system? Where do bat_in and bat_out connect? Should there be connectors for the input power and the bat connections? What's an ADW11?

Comment: rated current of tilt sensor is **2 mA MAX**. Current Ib =~ 5 mA ... and buzzer current = ~ 8 mA ...  Some things to check.

Comment: do you mean an excess tilt angle warning system?
- yes, sorry i'm not good at english

rated current of tilt sensor is 2 mA MAX
- yes, for using buzzer i think i have to add another transister

Comment: i found a new tilt sensor
SW-520D
12V / 20mA i think i can use this

Comment: it didn't work..

Comment: Perhaps change R4 -> 10k. Move buzzer serial with relay (just add a 5 V-0.5 W Zener parallel with buzzer) (?).

Comment: @KimJiHoon Are you trying to operate *both* the buzzer and also the 24 V relay when the tilt sensor is "closed?"

Comment: when closed -> poerating relay

when open  -> buzzer on

that is what i want and i'm trying to move tilt sensor to 2N3904's Emitter (GND)

Comment: @Antonio51
relay works, but buzzer keep ringing. doesn't off

Comment: Ok. Resistor R5 to be adjusted. Just check if BJT is OFF really. Or add another BJT for buzzer.

Comment: @Antonio51
i think add another BJT PNP&NPN both.

Comment: i removed the Buzzer part, and Relay doesn't off

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could be used ...
The capacitor is used at the start (24V effectively applied to the relay for working).

[image]

Comment: thank you! i'll try that

and i added 470u/16V capacitor between transistor's base-ground

because the output voltage very unstable(shakes) when the tilt sensor is almost horizontal.

Comment: Do it ticking "right" answer ...